# How do I validate my SSL certificate from a non-HTTP source in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

I don't understand those TrustManager classes and I thought it would be possible to validate against already installed root certificates on the device, but it looks like I have to install them by myself in the app.

I am obtaining my certificates from an external device in a raw ByteArray data and I want to create a CertPath which I could validate, but I don't know where should I get my root certificates from and I the internet focuses on web communication, which isn't the case here.